# Angular - Ng-change return always the same value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-group

I would like to ask, how can i get selected value from radio list?

I tried ng-change, and watch scope, but i get always only first value which is set into the model during the app initi.

Here is example of my code:

**Radio button group:**

```
<div class="list" ng-contoller="SettingsCtrl">
        <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'dials'">Dials</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'conversations'">Conversations</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'appoitnments'">Appointments</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'orders'">Orders</ion-radio>
      </div>
```

**JS:**

```
// Default choice scope
$scope.choice;

$scope.$watch('choice', function(value) {
            // Here i get always the same value
            console.log("Selected goalType, text: " +value);
});
```

How can i get selected value and set this value into the scope?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using ionic framework and with input radio buttons, it is working.
You've just make a mistake on this line `<div class="list" ng-contoller="SettingsCtrl">`.
You've forgotten an r in controller.

Here is the code working :
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.25" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <div class="list" ng-controller="SettingsCtrl">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'dials'">Dials
        <input type="radio" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'conversations'">Conversations
        <input type="radio" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'appoitnments'">Appointments
        <input type="radio" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'orders'">Orders
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And JavaScript :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.choice;
  console.log('ctrl');
  $scope.$watch('choice', function(value) {
              // Here i get always the same value
              console.log("Selected goalType, text: " +value);
  });
});
```

You can see it working here :
http://plnkr.co/edit/TRJKW7eOlBek6TditM1B?p=preview

**EDIT**
I've tested it with ionic framework. It is also working. So it was just the r the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6738/) for you. When you select a `radio`, `$scope.currentSelection` changes and this way you'll know which is the current selected goal.